# google ads "no ad to show" fail loading on release version only

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, admob

I checked other similar questions but it still doesnt work. I wanted to publish my app last week but for the moment I have no luck.

I am testing using the sample app for iOS from Google, and my own ad unit.
I created the ad unit about 3 weeks ago, and its not new account.

On simulators, the ads are showing like real ones but with the inscription "test mode".

When I tried on the real phone, they dont appear and I obtain a "no ad to show" error.
They only showing like real ones with the "test mode" if I add the phone identifier with the following:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers
```

But I never see real ads.

How can I obtain them to always appear in release version without inserting the phone identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the google team, waited for several days and it started wokring ok for no reason. I don't know what was the problem.